# JanusGraph with Solr

Tags: java, solr, cassandra, janusgraph, scylla

I am having problems with JanusGraph connecting to Solr: I have the following:

```
application.java
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JanusGraph g = JanusGraphFactory.open("/path/to/file/janusgraph-solr.properties");
        GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(g);
        g.close();
    }
```

janushgraph-solr.properties

```
# Change to the directory where JanusGraph was extracted.  Later commands
# use relative paths to the Solr config files shipped with the JanusGraph
# distribution.
cd $JANUSGRAPH_HOME

# The name must be URL safe and should contain one dot/full-stop
# character. The part of the name after the dot must not conflict with
# any of JanusGraph's internal CF names.  Starting the part after the dot
# "solr" will avoid a conflict with JanusGraph's internal CF names.
CORE_NAME=testt
# Where to upload collection configuration and send CoreAdmin requests.
SOLR_HOST=localhost:8983

# The value of index.[X].solr.http-urls in JanusGraph's config file
# should match $SOLR_HOST and $CORE_NAME.  For example, given the
# $CORE_NAME and $SOLR_HOST values above, JanusGraph's config file would
# contain (assuming "search" is the desired index alias):
#
 index.search.solr.http-urls=http://localhost:8983/solr/testt
#
# The stock JanusGraph config file conf/janusgraph-cassandra-solr.properties
# ships with this http-urls value.

storage.backend=cassandrathrift
```

GraphOfTheGods file: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-core/src/main/java/org/janusgraph/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not instantiate implementation: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.cassandra.thrift.CassandraThriftStoreManager

Caused by: org.janusgraph.diskstorage.TemporaryBackendException: Temporary failure in storage backend

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

How do i get rid of storage.backend=cassandrathrift and use solr as the backend? replacing "cassandrathrift" with solr as the document suggests fails for me. This results in the solr class not being found. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Enable thrift server on cassandra with `nodetool enablethrift`

Comment: @AshrafulIslam post as an answer so i can accept!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Enable thrift server on cassandra**

```
nodetool enablethrift
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your storage backend configuration from

```
storage.backend=cassandrathrift
```

to:

```
storage.backend=cql
```